# Python raytracing distorts object shapes when close to the camera

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, raytracing

**The Problem**

I recently found someone's awesome little pure-Python raytracing script [from this link](http://pastebin.com/f8f5ghjz), and extended it a little bit for more convenient functions. However, sometimes it distorts the shapes of the objects and I'm wondering if someone with raytracing/3d experience might have any clue as to what might be causing it?

**Some Info**

The scene I'm testing with consists of a ground-level plane with three colored spheres placed on top of it. It produces good-looking scenes when the camera is looking down on the scene from above/at angles and at a certain distance (see the first two pics); however, when the camera gets closer to the ground level and closer to the objects the spheres end up changing their shapes and becoming oblong as if they're being stretched up towards the sky (see third pic). Note that the camera in the third pic with the distorted spheres is sort of upside down, which is because I'm still figuring out how to control the camera and not sure how to "spin it" upright when that happens; it seems to automatically look towards the general area where the spheres/light source is located, and only if I change some parameters will it look in different directions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm still trying to decipher and understand what goes on in the original code that I found and based my code on, so I don't know but it could be something about the method or approach to raytracing taken by the original author. I've attached the entire code of my module script which should run when you press F5 if anyone is up for the challenge. The image rendering requires PIL, and if you want to play with the position of the camera, just look at the Camera class, and change its options in the "normaltest" function.

**Update**

Someone pointed out that when running the script it doesn't reproduce the problem in the third image. I have now changed the camera position for the normaltest function so that it will reproduce the problem (see the new fourth image for how it should look like). In case you're wondering why the light seems to be shooting out of the spheres it's bc I placed the lightsource somewhere in between all of them.

Im starting to think that the problem is with the camera and me not understanding it completely.

- The camera options zoom, xangle, and yangle may not do what their names imply; that's just how I named them based on what they seemed to do when I changed them up. Originally they were not variables but rather some constant nr in a calculation that had to be changed manually. Specifically they are used to define and produce the rays through the scene on line 218 in the renderScene function.
- For instance, sometimes when I change the zoom value it also changes the direction and position of the camera.
- It's a bit odd that in the original code the camera was just defined as a point with no direction (the xangle and yangle variables were at first just static nrs with no option for defining them), and almost always starts out looking towards the object automatically.
- I cant find a way to "spin"/tilt the camera around itself.

Try also to heighten the camera from its current z-coordinate of 2 to a z of 5, a very small change but it makes the distortion dramatically better looking (though still bad), so proximity to the ground or the shift in angle that comes with it seems to play some role.

```
"""
Pure Python ray-tracer :)
taken directly from http://pastebin.com/f8f5ghjz with modifications
another good one alternative at http://www.hxa.name/minilight/
some more equations for getting intersection with other 3d geometries, https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1999/AGraphHCI/SMAG/node2.html#SECTION00023200000000000000
"""

#IMPORTS
from math import sqrt, pow, pi
import time
import PIL,PIL.Image

#GEOMETRIES
class Vector( object ):

    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def dot(self, b):
        return self.x*b.x + self.y*b.y + self.z*b.z

    def cross(self, b):
        return (self.y*b.z-self.z*b.y, self.z*b.x-self.x*b.z, self.x*b.y-self.y*b.x)

    def magnitude(self):
        return sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2+self.z**2)

    def normal(self):
        mag = self.magnitude()
        return Vector(self.x/mag,self.y/mag,self.z/mag)

    def __add__(self, b):
        return Vector(self.x + b.x, self.y+b.y, self.z+b.z)

    def __sub__(self, b):
        return Vector(self.x-b.x, self.y-b.y, self.z-b.z)

    def __mul__(self, b):
        assert type(b) == float or type(b) == int
        return Vector(self.x*b, self.y*b, self.z*b)     

class Sphere( object ):

    def __init__(self, center, radius, color):
        self.c = center
        self.r = radius
        self.col = color

    def intersection(self, l):
        q = l.d.dot(l.o - self.c)**2 - (l.o - self.c).dot(l.o - self.c) + self.r**2
        if q < 0:
            return Intersection( Vector(0,0,0), -1, Vector(0,0,0), self)
        else:
            d = -l.d.dot(l.o - self.c)
            d1 = d - sqrt(q)
            d2 = d + sqrt(q)
            if 0 < d1 and ( d1 < d2 or d2 < 0):
                return Intersection(l.o+l.d*d1, d1, self.normal(l.o+l.d*d1), self)
            elif 0 < d2 and ( d2 < d1 or d1 < 0):
                return Intersection(l.o+l.d*d2, d2, self.normal(l.o+l.d*d2), self)
            else:
                return Intersection( Vector(0,0,0), -1, Vector(0,0,0), self)    

    def normal(self, b):
        return (b - self.c).normal()

class Cylinder( object ):

    "just a copy of sphere, needs work. maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078401/trying-to-optimize-line-vs-cylinder-intersection"

    def __init__(self, startpoint, endpoint, radius, color):
        self.s = startpoint
        self.e = endpoint
        self.r = radius
        self.col = color

    def intersection(self, l):
        q = l.d.dot(l.o - self.c)**2 - (l.o - self.c).dot(l.o - self.c) + self.r**2
        if q < 0:
            return Intersection( Vector(0,0,0), -1, Vector(0,0,0), self)
        else:
            d = -l.d.dot(l.o - self.c)
            d1 = d - sqrt(q)
            d2 = d + sqrt(q)
            if 0 < d1 and ( d1 < d2 or d2 < 0):
                return Intersection(l.o+l.d*d1, d1, self.normal(l.o+l.d*d1), self)
            elif 0 < d2 and ( d2 < d1 or d1 < 0):
                return Intersection(l.o+l.d*d2, d2, self.normal(l.o+l.d*d2), self)
            else:
                return Intersection( Vector(0,0,0), -1, Vector(0,0,0), self)    

    def normal(self, b):
        return (b - self.c).normal()

class LightBulb( Sphere ):
        pass

class Plane( object ):
    "infinite, no endings"
    def __init__(self, point, normal, color):
        self.n = normal
        self.p = point
        self.col = color

    def intersection(self, l):
        d = l.d.dot(self.n)
        if d == 0:
            return Intersection( vector(0,0,0), -1, vector(0,0,0), self)
        else:
            d = (self.p - l.o).dot(self.n) / d
            return Intersection(l.o+l.d*d, d, self.n, self)

class Rectangle( object ):
    "not done. like a plane, but is limited to the shape of a defined rectangle"
    def __init__(self, point, normal, color):
        self.n = normal
        self.p = point
        self.col = color

    def intersection(self, ray):
        desti = ray.dest.dot(self.n)
        if desti == 0:
                        #??
            return Intersection( vector(0,0,0), -1, vector(0,0,0), self)
        else:
            desti = (self.p - ray.orig).dot(self.n) / desti
            return Intersection(ray.orig+ray.desti*desti, desti, self.n, self)

class RectangleBox( object ):
        "not done. consists of multiple rectangle objects as its sides"
        pass

class AnimatedObject( object ):

        def __init__(self, *objs):
                self.objs = objs

        def __iter__(self):
                for obj in self.objs:
                        yield obj

        def __getitem__(self, index):
                return self.objs[index]

        def reverse(self):
                self.objs = [each for each in reversed(self.objs)]
                return self

#RAY TRACING INTERNAL COMPONENTS
class Ray( object ):

    def __init__(self, origin, direction):
        self.o = origin
        self.d = direction

class Intersection( object ):
    "keeps a record of a known intersection bw ray and obj?"
    def __init__(self, point, distance, normal, obj):
        self.p = point
        self.d = distance
        self.n = normal
        self.obj = obj

def testRay(ray, objects, ignore=None):
    intersect = Intersection( Vector(0,0,0), -1, Vector(0,0,0), None)

    for obj in objects:
        if obj is not ignore:
            currentIntersect = obj.intersection(ray)
            if currentIntersect.d > 0 and intersect.d < 0:
                intersect = currentIntersect
            elif 0 < currentIntersect.d < intersect.d:
                intersect = currentIntersect
    return intersect

def trace(ray, objects, light, maxRecur):
    if maxRecur < 0:
        return (0,0,0)
    intersect = testRay(ray, objects)       
    if intersect.d == -1:
        col = vector(AMBIENT,AMBIENT,AMBIENT)
    elif intersect.n.dot(light - intersect.p) < 0:
        col = intersect.obj.col * AMBIENT
    else:
        lightRay = Ray(intersect.p, (light-intersect.p).normal())
        if testRay(lightRay, objects, intersect.obj).d == -1:
            lightIntensity = 1000.0/(4*pi*(light-intersect.p).magnitude()**2)
            col = intersect.obj.col * max(intersect.n.normal().dot((light - intersect.p).normal()*lightIntensity), AMBIENT)
        else:
            col = intersect.obj.col * AMBIENT
    return col

def gammaCorrection(color,factor):
    return (int(pow(color.x/255.0,factor)*255),
            int(pow(color.y/255.0,factor)*255),
            int(pow(color.z/255.0,factor)*255))

#USER FUNCTIONS
class Camera:

    def __init__(self, cameraPos, zoom=50.0, xangle=-5, yangle=-5):
        self.pos = cameraPos
        self.zoom = zoom
        self.xangle = xangle
        self.yangle = yangle

def renderScene(camera, lightSource, objs, imagedims, savepath):
        imgwidth,imgheight = imagedims
        img = PIL.Image.new("RGB",imagedims)
        #objs.append( LightBulb(lightSource, 0.2, Vector(*white)) )
        print "rendering 3D scene"
        t=time.clock()
        for x in xrange(imgwidth):
                #print x
                for y in xrange(imgheight):
                        ray = Ray( camera.pos, (Vector(x/camera.zoom+camera.xangle,y/camera.zoom+camera.yangle,0)-camera.pos).normal())
                        col = trace(ray, objs, lightSource, 10)
                        img.putpixel((x,imgheight-1-y),gammaCorrection(col,GAMMA_CORRECTION))
        print "time taken", time.clock()-t
        img.save(savepath)

def renderAnimation(camera, lightSource, staticobjs, animobjs, imagedims, savepath, saveformat):
        "NOTE: savepath should not have file extension, but saveformat should have a dot"
        time = 0
        while True:
                print "time",time
                timesavepath = savepath+"_"+str(time)+saveformat
                objs = []
                objs.extend(staticobjs)
                objs.extend([animobj[time] for animobj in animobjs])
                renderScene(camera, lightSource, objs, imagedims, timesavepath)
                time += 1

#SOME LIGHTNING OPTIONS
AMBIENT = 0.05 #daylight/nighttime
GAMMA_CORRECTION = 1/2.2 #lightsource strength?

#COLORS
red = (255,0,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
grey = (120,120,120)
white = (255,255,255)
purple = (200,0,200)

def origtest():
        print ""
        print "origtest"
        #BUILD THE SCENE
        imagedims = (500,500)
        savepath = "3dscene_orig.png"
        objs = []
        objs.append(Sphere( Vector(-2,0,-10), 2, Vector(*green)))      
        objs.append(Sphere( Vector(2,0,-10), 3.5, Vector(*red)))
        objs.append(Sphere( Vector(0,-4,-10), 3, Vector(*blue)))
        objs.append(Plane( Vector(0,0,-12), Vector(0,0,1), Vector(*grey)))
        lightSource = Vector(0,10,0)
        camera = Camera(Vector(0,0,20))

        #RENDER
        renderScene(camera, lightSource, objs, imagedims, savepath)

def normaltest():
        print ""
        print "normaltest"
        #BUILD THE SCENE
        """
        the camera is looking down on the surface with the spheres from above
        the surface is like looking down on the xy axis of the xyz coordinate system
        the light is down there together with the spheres, except from one of the sides
        """
        imagedims = (200,200)
        savepath = "3dscene.png"
        objs = []
        objs.append(Sphere( Vector(-4, -2, 1), 1, Vector(*red)))
        objs.append(Sphere( Vector(-2, -2, 1), 1, Vector(*blue)))
        objs.append(Sphere( Vector(-2, -4, 1), 1, Vector(*green)))
        objs.append(Plane( Vector(0,0,0), Vector(0,0,1), Vector(*grey)))
        lightSource = Vector(-2.4, -3, 2)
        camera = Camera(Vector(-19,-19,2), zoom=2.0, xangle=-30, yangle=-30)

        #RENDER
        renderScene(camera, lightSource, objs, imagedims, savepath)

def animtest():
        print ""
        print "falling ball test"
        #BUILD THE SCENE
        imagedims = (200,200)
        savepath = "3d_fallball"
        saveformat = ".png"
        staticobjs = []
        staticobjs.append(Sphere( Vector(-4, -2, 1), 1, Vector(*red)))
        staticobjs.append(Sphere( Vector(-2, -4, 1), 1, Vector(*green)))
        staticobjs.append(Plane( Vector(0,0,0), Vector(0,0,1), Vector(*purple)))
        animobjs = []
        fallingball = AnimatedObject(Sphere( Vector(-2, -2, 20), 1, Vector(*yellow)),
                                     Sphere( Vector(-2, -2, 15), 1, Vector(*yellow)),
                                     Sphere( Vector(-2, -2, 9), 1, Vector(*yellow)),
                                     Sphere( Vector(-2, -2, 5), 1, Vector(*yellow)),
                                     Sphere( Vector(-2, -2, 1), 1, Vector(*yellow)))
        animobjs.append(fallingball)
        lightSource = Vector(-4,-4,10)
        camera = Camera(Vector(0,0,30))

        #RENDER
        renderAnimation(camera, lightSource, staticobjs, animobjs, imagedims, savepath, saveformat)

#RUN TESTS
#origtest()
normaltest()
#animtest()
```

Comment: How do you generate the broken third image. I can't seem to get anything which looks wrong.

Comment: Probably not the cause of the (or any) problem (yet) since your image is square, but in `renderScene`, the line should probably read `for y in yrange`.

Comment: I'm not certain, but the part that looks suspicious is the constant zoom factor in the camera. In real photography, excessive zoom can cause strange distortions on nearby objects. So I'd suggest trying a lower value when the camera is very close.

Comment: @luserdroog is almost certainly on the money. With a raytracer like this, something often forgotten is viewing angle. Depending on how the camera is implemented, it may compute the viewing angle based on distance from where it is pointing. Consequently, the viewing angle explodes as you get "closer" to the ground, but the size of the output image stays the same. This leads to the "stretch" effect you observe -- the larger viewing angle is compressed into a frame of the same size. I've run into something similar when writing raytracers in the past.

Comment: I like all these tips :) Salix alba, my bad, I have now updated the code with the camera settings to produce the problem (see image 4). Luserdroog, xrange isnt what u think, its just a nrsrange generator, and I tried decreasing the zoom variable but the spheres actually got thinner. @ProgrammerDan what you say about viewing angle makes sense, have u been able to spot where the code for viewangle is? Might that be in the renderScene func where the ray is created based on camera options, ca line 218? Theres def something fishy with the whole camera thing, see my updated question for details.

Comment: @KarimBahgat You've got the right line of code in mind. If you look closely at the line you've highlighted, you'll notice that it is design to "blast" the area surrounding the Z axis with "rays". I believe the xangle/yangle stuff controls the viewing angles along the axis. You've got a couple of options. On the easy end, just move your objects if you want a different perspective on them. On the other end, get familiar with trigonometry and adjust the true angle of the camera, not the viewing angles.

Comment: I would suggest you look at this website www.scratchapixel.com to learn about ray tracing. Particularly, with regards to your problem these 2 lessons: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-7-intersecting-simple-shapes/ and http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-6-rays-cameras-and-images/

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problems is probably this line:

```
ray = Ray( camera.pos, 
     (Vector(
        x/camera.zoom+camera.xangle,
        y/camera.zoom+camera.yangle,
        0)
     -camera.pos)
     .normal())
```

A ray is defined as a line going from camera position (however is that point defined) over XY plane, that is zoomed and SHIFTED by the xangle and yangle parameters.

This is not how perspective projection is usually implemented. This is more like a tilt/shift camera. A typical perspective transform would keep the plane you project onto PERPENDICULAR to the ray going from the camera through the centre of the picture.

With this code you have two options: either rewrite this, or always use xangle, yangle, camera.pos.x and camera.pos.y == 0. Otherwise you get wonky results.

To be correct, this is perfectly legit perspective. It is just not what you would ever see with a typical camera.

Comment: I would suggest you look at this website www.scratchapixel.com to learn about ray tracing. Particularly, with regards to your problem these 2 lessons: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-7-intersecting-simple-shapes/ and http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-6-rays-cameras-and-images/